# Is there a way to serve up web pages for URLs that don't have an actual backing page?

Tags: php, html, url, webserver

I'm curious to know if there is a way to have URLs be intercepted by a PHP page or some other server side logic such that if the URL "www.mysite.com/about/mission_statement" is queried but I don't have a page at "about/mission_statement", that I can serve up the content from, say, "some/other/folder/with/pages".

Does anybody know if this is possible, or do I have to ensure that I have a page available for every url address I wish to handle?

Comment: We used a 404 handler for this on our system, it is a hack and it confuses us from time to time!  In fact for a while we never had any 404's!   So I really would encourage the solution by Eric J as it will allow you to control the url patterns that you want to redirect as valid, and still potentially use a 404 handler for, well, 404's.

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. It's a simple way to solve the problem. Ideally, add a 404 script that can handle 404's separately :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that in PHP directly because a PHP page is invoked in order to process a given URL, but you can do that in your web server.

Assuming Apache have a look at URL rewriting

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

In particular for your case, the subtopic

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html

is relevant.

IIS has a similar capability.

Answer (score 2):

Again presuming your using Apache, then you have a number of options:

Use a Rewrite rule (as specified in another answer) for specific pages/content or include a line in your .htaccess file that redirects any requests that don't exist (404's) to a specific location/file of your choice.

This is usually envoked using the following code in an [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file either in your docroot directory or other directory of choice:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /whatever/path/to/file.php
```

If your using dynamic pages in PHP keyed by, say ID or some other dynamic value, EG:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/page.php?id=4
```

then you need to create a function that redirects to your page of choice if the content doesn't match or exist.

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to the ErrorDocument handler, that should prove useful too.